# Undefined index: timezone in Laravel

Tags: php, git, laravel

I have developed a Laravel project locally on a Mac running MAMP. I have this in a Git Repo. I have attempted to Git Clone, Composer Update on my deployment server, however I get the following output:

```
smpuser@ssmpuser:/var/www/recruitment-v2$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing stack/builder (dev-master f98a5eb)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing phpseclib/phpseclib (dev-master 268ec2e)
  - Installing phpseclib/phpseclib (dev-master 211e237)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing monolog/monolog (dev-master d81ca5a)
  - Installing monolog/monolog (dev-master 7f783c0)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing nikic/php-parser (dev-master 0353c92)
  - Installing nikic/php-parser (dev-master bf9956b)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing predis/predis (0.8.x-dev 0f01b89)
  - Installing predis/predis (0.8.x-dev 5f2eea6)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Removing laravel/framework (4.1.x-dev 6e246f3)
  - Installing laravel/framework (4.1.x-dev 24c9aaf)
    Downloading: connection...    Downloading: 100%         

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined index: timezone","file":"\/var\/www\/recruitment-v2\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/start.php","line":167}}{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined index: timezone","file":"\/var\/www\/recruitment-v2\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/start.php","line":167}}
```

I have tried this on 3 servers now and get the same issue, I am running PHP 5.3.10.

Can anybody suggest a fix?

Here is my start.php, which is bundled with Laravel.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Set PHP Error Reporting Options
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will set the strictest error reporting options, and also turn
| off PHP's error reporting, since all errors will be handled by the
| framework and we don't want any output leaking back to the user.
|
*/

error_reporting(-1);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check Extensions
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel requires a few extensions to function. Here we will check the
| loaded extensions to make sure they are present. If not we'll just
| bail from here. Otherwise, Composer will crazily fall back code.
|
*/

if ( ! extension_loaded('mcrypt'))
{
    echo 'Mcrypt PHP extension required.'.PHP_EOL;

    exit(1);
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Class Imports
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will just import a few classes that we need during the booting
| of the framework. These are mainly classes that involve loading the
| config files for this application, such as the config repository.
|
*/

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
use Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader;
use Illuminate\Config\EnvironmentVariables;
use Illuminate\Config\Repository as Config;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Bind The Application In The Container
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This may look strange, but we actually want to bind the app into itself
| in case we need to Facade test an application. This will allow us to
| resolve the "app" key out of this container for this app's facade.
|
*/

$app->instance('app', $app);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check For The Test Environment
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the "unitTesting" variable is set, it means we are running the unit
| tests for the application and should override this environment here
| so we use the right configuration. The flag gets set by TestCase.
|
*/

if (isset($unitTesting))
{
    $app['env'] = $env = $testEnvironment;
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Load The Illuminate Facades
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The facades provide a terser static interface over the various parts
| of the application, allowing their methods to be accessed through
| a mixtures of magic methods and facade derivatives. It's slick.
|
*/

Facade::clearResolvedInstances();

Facade::setFacadeApplication($app);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Facade Aliases To Full Classes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default, we use short keys in the container for each of the core
| pieces of the framework. Here we will register the aliases for a
| list of all of the fully qualified class names making DI easy.
|
*/

$app->registerCoreContainerAliases();

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Environment Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will register all of the $_ENV and $_SERVER variables into the
| process so that they're globally available configuration options so
| sensitive configuration information can be swept out of the code.
|
*/

with($envVariables = new EnvironmentVariables(
    $app->getEnvironmentVariablesLoader()))->load($env);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Configuration Repository
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The configuration repository is used to lazily load in the options for
| this application from the configuration files. The files are easily
| separated by their concerns so they do not become really crowded.
|
*/

$app->instance('config', $config = new Config(

    $app->getConfigLoader(), $env

));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Application Exception Handling
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We will go ahead and register the application exception handling here
| which will provide a great output of exception details and a stack
| trace in the case of exceptions while an application is running.
|
*/

$app->startExceptionHandling();

if ($env != 'testing') ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Set The Default Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will set the default timezone for PHP. PHP is notoriously mean
| if the timezone is not explicitly set. This will be used by each of
| the PHP date and date-time functions throughout the application.
|
*/

$config = $app['config']['app'];

date_default_timezone_set($config['timezone']);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Alias Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The alias loader is responsible for lazy loading the class aliases setup
| for the application. We will only register it if the "config" service
| is bound in the application since it contains the alias definitions.
|
*/

$aliases = $config['aliases'];

AliasLoader::getInstance($aliases)->register();

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enable HTTP Method Override
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next we will tell the request class to allow HTTP method overriding
| since we use this to simulate PUT and DELETE requests from forms
| as they are not currently supported by plain HTML form setups.
|
*/

Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Core Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The Illuminate core service providers register all of the core pieces
| of the Illuminate framework including session, caching, encryption
| and more. It's simply a convenient wrapper for the registration.
|
*/

$providers = $config['providers'];

$app->getProviderRepository()->load($app, $providers);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Booted Start Files
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once the application has been booted there are several "start" files
| we will want to include. We'll register our "booted" handler here
| so the files are included after the application gets booted up.
|
*/

$app->booted(function() use ($app, $env)
{

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Load The Application Start Script
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The start script gives us the application the opportunity to override
| any of the existing IoC bindings, as well as register its own new
| bindings for things like repositories, etc. We'll load it here.
|
*/

$path = $app['path'].'/start/global.php';

if (file_exists($path)) require $path;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Load The Environment Start Script
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The environment start script is only loaded if it exists for the app
| environment currently active, which allows some actions to happen
| in one environment while not in the other, keeping things clean.
|
*/

$path = $app['path']."/start/{$env}.php";

if (file_exists($path)) require $path;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Load The Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The Application routes are kept separate from the application starting
| just to keep the file a little cleaner. We'll go ahead and load in
| all of the routes now and return the application to the callers.
|
*/

$routes = $app['path'].'/routes.php';

if (file_exists($routes)) require $routes;

});
```

app.php:

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => 'http://x.x.co.uk',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => 'U6rUNcyOZASCypuYCZAB5CGvWaNkjcEm',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => array(

        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\CommandsServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\MigrationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\SeedServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',

    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Service Provider Manifest
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service provider manifest is used by Laravel to lazy load service
    | providers which are not needed for each request, as well to keep a
    | list of all of the services. Here, you may set its storage spot.
    |
    */

    'manifest' => storage_path().'/meta',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => array(

        'App'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
        'Artisan'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
        'Auth'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
        'Blade'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade',
        'Cache'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache',
        'ClassLoader'     => 'Illuminate\Support\ClassLoader',
        'Config'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config',
        'Controller'      => 'Illuminate\Routing\Controller',
        'Cookie'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie',
        'Crypt'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt',
        'DB'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB',
        'Eloquent'        => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
        'Event'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
        'File'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
        'Form'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Form',
        'Hash'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash',
        'HTML'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\HTML',
        'Input'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input',
        'Lang'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang',
        'Log'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
        'Mail'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
        'Paginator'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator',
        'Password'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password',
        'Queue'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue',
        'Redirect'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect',
        'Redis'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',
        'Request'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request',
        'Response'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
        'Route'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
        'Schema'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema',
        'Seeder'          => 'Illuminate\Database\Seeder',
        'Session'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
        'SSH'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\SSH',
        'Str'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Str',
        'URL'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL',
        'Validator'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator',
        'View'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\View',

    ),

);
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your `start.php` ?

Comment: It's the base Laravel start.php, I haven't modified it. Included it in the post above.

Comment: can you post your `app.php` from the `config` directory?

Comment: Included app.php, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce that error by leaving out configuration files in `app/config/` directory:

If you happen to `dd()` the config variable within that file, you will notice that it is empty.

I came across that same problem when working with `git` and branches that tried to ignore parts of the config folder that were needed.

I would suggest double checking your settings within that folder along with any `.gitignore` rules associated with that folder.  If you are missing those files, make sure to download them manually and put them in your `app/config/` directory.

I hope that points you in the right direction, because I was totally lost with that error.

Answer (score 1):

Do you set the timezone in your php.ini? For example:

```
date.timezone = Europe/Rome
```

Comment: Yes its set to Europe/London, this doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

add date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London"); at the top of the main page or inside constructor if you are using class.